# How to make diferent post formats for different pages?

Tags: posts

I am making a word press theme. I want different post format of blog page and category page!
Here is an example of what i am trying to say

http://zeequotes.com

This web site have different post formats of blog page and category page!
but i want to know where to add the codes! In index.php or ?

Comment: Even with following the link it is impossible to understand what are you asking. Please edit the question to make it clearer. Post formats For example is probably the wrong terminology for what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create either a child theme based on a current theme you are already using, or develop your own custom theme.  Within your theme, you'll have complete control over the layouts used for single posts and category pages (knowns as archives).

A great place to start is with the WordPress documentation at wordpress.org.  The article on [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) is very helpful and will guide you on the proper use of [template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)